# Texture does not seem right

Tags: texturing, uv

I imported a file into blender, but it seems the texture is a little bit weird.
the grey object should be a bitumen roof. the side looks good, the top and the bottom are just weird.
Even though the wrapping mode is "repeat", the top and bottom seem to have the wrapping mode "Clamp", at least that's what it looks like

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it? or more - what is the problem? are the uv coordinates wrong?

Here is the building I am working on:

[image]

... with a closer look to the roof:
[image]

and here is the texture I added to the roof:

[image]

Comment: Hello, it must have to do with your material setup, maybe show a screenshot, or pack your image and share the roof object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your node set-up looks like, so I can't tell if there's a problem with that, but it could also be a problem with the UV. In that case it's pretty easy to fix.

1. In normal mode, press ctrl+a and then select Rotation and Scale. This will apply the rotation and scale of the object.

[image]

2. In edit mode, press "a" to select all the verticies and then go to "UV" and click on "Smart UV Project". This will fix the UV.

[image]

Hope that this helped, if not I think there's a problem with the node set-up.